# Angular2 2.0.0-beta.9 gives build errors

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 project in visual studio that was working using 2.0.0-beta.0.  I have upgraded to 2.0.0-beta.9 and I'm getting build errors.

The first error is:

> Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.

Also in the "TypeScript Virtual Projects    " project.

The file is:

> MyProject\node_modules\angular2\src\facade\collection.d.ts

As a test I used the package.json from the Quickstart here:
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need some ambient typings in your tsconfig.json

```
"files": [
  "typings/browser/ambient/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts",
  "typings/browser/ambient/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.ts"
],
```

In command line (at the project root level) do:

```
typings install --save --ambient es6-promise es6-collections

// If you don't have typings installed do:
// npm install -g typings
```